# Имитация клика по фрейму

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

На страничку встроен Iframe. Как при помощи Jquery или JS совершать клики по определенным координатам фрейма с определенной частотой (30 секунд)?

Comment: @RomanAnanev, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

С Jquery:

```
 $(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).click();
```

Осталось получить координаты фрейма и выполнить вышеприведенный код. [Тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint) почитайте еще, если нужно.

Без Jquery:

```
function click(x,y){
  var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
  var el = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
  ev.initMouseEvent(
    "click",
    true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */,
    window, null,
    x, y, 0, 0, /* coordinates */
    false, false, false, false, /* modifier keys */
    0 /*left*/, null
  );
  el.dispatchEvent(ev);
}
```

Совсем забыл про периодичность в 30 секунд:

```
function func() {
 alert('Привет');
}
setTimeout(func, 30000);  //Выполниться один раз через 30 секунд
setInterval(func, 30000); //Будет выполняться каждые 30 секунд
```